# How can I do unit tests on a java socket game that uses a game loop?

Tags: java, unit-testing

**The problem**

I have finished coding a game in java called Apples To Apples and now I am trying to make unit tests. I have a main class that acts as the server and it supports multiplayer by using socket programming. The constructor of the server consists of setting up the game, adding players and then running the game in a while loop. I have created methods that are called in the while loop for each phase of the game.

I have now created a test class to make unit tests of each method (phases of the game) and this is where my problem arises. I don't know how to access the methods from the server class in the best way. I first tried to make an instance of the server class but this results in the test just running forever waiting for the game to finish. Then I tried to access the methods without instantiating the server class but this results in having to change the methods and some variables to static and I have read that you should avoid making variables static.

So my question is, is there another approach I am missing here or is there anything I can do different?

**Simplified version of my problem**

```
public class Apples2ApplesServer{

private String card = "Wildcard!";

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Apples2ApplesServer(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
}

Apples2ApplesServer(int numOfOnlinePlayers){
    setupGame();
    addPlayers(numOfOnlinePlayers);

    // Game loop
    while (true){
        System.out.print(phaseOne());
    }
}

public static String phaseOne(){
    return card;
}
```

}

```
class Apples2ApplesServerTest {

// My first approach, does not work
Apples2ApplesServer server = new Apples2ApplesServer(1);

@Test
@DisplayName("Test phase one")
void phaseOneTest(){
    // My second approach
    // Works but phaseOne and card needs to be static
    String firstCard = Apples2ApplesServer.phaseOne();
    assertEquals("Wildcard!", firstCard);
}
```

}

If you want to take a look at the entire code you can find it on my [github](https://github.com/eliazz95/ApplesToApples/tree/main/src).
Also, this is my first time asking for help here so i'd love feedback on how I presented my problem :)

Comment: Sounds like you're really asking about integration testing. If you aren't already, you should consider whether a mocking framework like Mockito would help you write more complete *unit* tests (including getting server side unit test coverage). For integration tests where you still want the client to actually invoke server code, you could have a setup phase before each test where a new thread or even a process is started. Have a short "waiting" loop which blocks test execution until the thread or process is ready, run the test, and then shut down the server side. Yeah, UT are way easier.

Comment: Sounds like you made your game working, but the code is not really testable as it is.
First of all, I would add a "running" Flag (`AtomicBoolean` or `volatile boolean`) which can stop the game-loop gracefully (also helpful when you want to code a regular shutdown).
Then I would hide the networking code behind interface(s) (thats where the actual software engineering kicks in) so you can test your overall code without actually opening any sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem testing the game loop is very similar to testing other server or daemon code.

Not a real solution, but you might want to check out how other projects like Apache Tomcat go testing their overall server. That too, once started up would keep running until a shutdown command is received.